# Questions about filtering return values and the expected return type in Apache beam for python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have two questions about using the Apache Beam for Python (Google Cloud Dataflow) to develop map-reduce pipelines.

To start, whenever I'm performing any sort of `beam.DoFn()` or `beam.Map()` function something like this happens

```
def function(input):
  if not input > 0:
    return None
  else:
    return input*2

p = beam.Pipeline()

(p
 | 'read some input from a source'
 >> read_from_datastore(some_query)
 | 'perform an operation on the input'
 >> beam.Map(function)
 | 'filter out invalid values'
 >> beam.Filter(lambda x: x is not None)
)
```

Some sort of error case is handled within the mapping function, and I return None instead of the expected mapped value. I then have to add a `beam.Filter()` step to remove all `None` values from entering the next stage of the pipeline. This ends up being extremely verbose and annoying to handle in pipelines with many different stages. Is there some type of way to tell the function to automatically filter any `None` return values? Or just tell the function to not return anything at all?

Secondly, is the return type of `beam.Map` and `beam.DoFn` supposed to be a list? It seems that whenever I take in a single value and return a single value things begin to break. I often find myself encapsulating a single return value (like an int) in brackets to cast it to a list, that way the next stage of my pipeline receives just that single int. I must be missing something about the expected structure and flow of a map-reduce pipeline, is a single stage in the pipeline supposed to return a list-like object?

Comment: "I often find myself encapsulating a single return value (like an int) in brackets to cast it to a list,"

Can you provide more details/sample_code/error_text on this?

Answer (score 0):

- is the return type of beam.Map and beam.DoFn supposed to be a list?

  - No, that is incorrect for .Map. If you're implementing ParDo, then pardo is expected to output list.
- tell the function to not return anything at all?

  - You can use .FlatMap() and return empty list. Map is intended for 1:1 transforms. [Ultimately, .Map uses .FlatMap internall](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/6d56040890eeecff15e364871ab5d3016dde1e6f/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/core.py#L1372)y.